# Use record in several namespaces

Tags: function, clojure, namespaces, record

I have clojure file with some predefined functions and records

```
;outer.clj
(ns outer )
(defn foo [a] (println a))
(defrecord M [id])
```

And now usage file

```
;inner.clj
(ns inner (:use outer ))
(foo 2)    ;works fine
(println (:id (M. 4))) ;throws IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: M
```

Why does function imports fine but records definition doesn't? How I should import it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because defrecord generates a JVM class 'under the covers' you need to import that class...

```
;inner.clj
(ns inner 
    (:use outer )
    (:import outer.M)
(foo 2)    ;works fine
(println (:id (M. 4))) ; works with import
```

Answer (score 4):

While sw1nn is correct, since 1.3 you needn't go through a separate import. Both `defrecord` and `deftype` also create constructor functions, which would be available via `use`/`require` just like any other function.

The function created by both follows the form `->MyType` and takes positional args.

Additionally, `defrecord` creates a second constructor function that takes a map arg, `map->MyRecord`.

Comment: Thanks for providing more info.